# Erlang Front-End Admin Panel

Tags: frameworks, erlang, ejabberd, mochiweb

We're looking for a framework in which we can assign multiple roles to different users and allow those users to in turn manipulate certain data (based on their role).  We have an ejabberd backend and a Mochiweb (BeepBeep framework) front end, and the nodes are connected so Mochiweb can manipulate ejabberd's mnesia tables.

Does a direct solution exist?  If not would anyone recommend Ruby on Rails? (and which Rails app if there is one should we use?)

Lastly, if none exist, where's a good place to find some solid Erlang programmers for us to hire for this job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your asking for here. Do you want a framework that handles ACLs for your users? Or do you want a whole package sort of thing that does the whole package? Or is it something else? I'm not even sure where RoR would fit in with what you describe.

Comment: Leaning towards the Whole Package.  If these are only custom made (which makes total sense), I'm open to suggestions for where to go to find the right developers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only actively-developed RoR-like framework for Erlang is [ChicagoBoss](http://www.chicagoboss.org/)